# Python Regex match: include Regex syntax

Tags: python, regex

This is a list of characters I need for a regex match:

```
A-Za-z0-9_-\[]{}^`|
```

However, some of them, like `\`, `[]`, `^` and `|` are regex syntax characters, when I tried using this pattern, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    if re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9_-\[]{}^`|]*$", weird_input):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: bad character range
```

Is there any way I could include those characters?

Comment: backslash is the escaping char in regex

Comment: put a \ before -, [, ], and any other special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape them using `\` like:

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wC5yP0/2)

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'[A-Za-z0-9_\-\\\[\]\{\}^`\|]+')
test_str = u"test"

re.match(p, test_str)
```

Comment: not necessarily every punctuation. for example, ^ is normal character if it does not appear in the first place of a character set

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr you are correct, I let myself carried away with the `\\` :D

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Also thanks for the link to the regex101 website, will bookmark it in case I have issues with Regex in the future. :)

Comment: Shouldn't this work too? `[A-Za-z0-9_\-\\[\]{}^`|]+`